# How to merge multiple rows in time series data having same time into a single record using Python?

Tags: python, sorting, time-series, unique

I have a time series data wherein measurement values from different sensors have been captured asynchronously and concatenated into same ascii file. The sensor values have been captured at the same time instance.

The values are white space separated.

Original file looks like below.

```
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED                1.00
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED                1.00
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED                1.00
```

Now I need to replace the string `NOTSAMPLED` with the previous instance sensor value as mentioned below and also merge sensor values spread across multiple rows and columns into single row having same time.

```
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10               1.00       0.0     1.0
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11               1.00       0.0     1.0
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12               1.00       0.0     1.0
```

Similarly if input data is

```
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 880 10          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED               10.00
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 395 11          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED               11.00
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12                1.00       NOTSAMPLED          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12          NOTSAMPLED             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 15 900 12          NOTSAMPLED       NOTSAMPLED               12.00
```

Then my expected output should be

```
2022 281 08 48 14 876 10                1.00             0.00          NOTSAMPLED
2022 281 08 48 14 880 10                1.00             0.00               10.00
2022 281 08 48 15 391 11                1.00             0.00               10.00
2022 281 08 48 15 395 11                1.00             0.00               11.00
2022 281 08 48 15 896 12                1.00             0.00               11.00
2022 281 08 48 15 900 12                1.00             0.00               12.00
```

How can it be done using core python ?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I just realized you asked for it to be done in core python, but I will leave my answer in case it helps anyone in the future.

You can use `pd.read_fwf` along with the start/stop ranges of each column to properly read the file into a dataframe.  Then you can replace `NOTSAMPLED` with nan, groupby the date and get the first non-null value from each group.

The last step is to forward fill the resulting data and replace any initial nulls with `NOTSAMPLED`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_fwf('del.txt', colspecs=[(0,24),(34,44), (51,61),(71,81)], header=None)
df = df.replace('NOTSAMPLED', np.nan).groupby(0, as_index=False).first().ffill().fillna('NOTSAMPLED')

print(df)
```

Output

```
                          0     1     2           3
0  2022 281 08 48 14 876 10  1.00  0.00  NOTSAMPLED
1  2022 281 08 48 14 880 10  1.00  0.00       10.00
2  2022 281 08 48 15 391 11  1.00  0.00       10.00
3  2022 281 08 48 15 395 11  1.00  0.00       11.00
4  2022 281 08 48 15 896 12  1.00  0.00       11.00
5  2022 281 08 48 15 900 12  1.00  0.00       12.00
```

Comment: thanks a lot. How it can be done without using pandas and using core python only ?

Comment: I'm sure it could be done, but it's more complicated than I would be willing to help you with given that you've shown no effort to try and do it yourself.